# A way to load data into entity based on Id. Model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

It is an  ASP.NET MVC project,

ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class QuestionViewModel
{
    public CheckListsQuestion CheckListsQuestion { get; set; } //this is EF entity
    public string Points { get; set; }
}
```

The view looks somehow like

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<WebCheckList.Models.QuestionViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "CheckList" ... )
{
    foreach (var viewModel in Model)
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="[@counter].CheckListsQuestion.ID"  value="@viewModel.CheckListsQuestion.ID" />
        <input type="number" name="[@counter].Points" >
    }
}
```

If I try to make it like

```
<input type="hidden" name="[@counter].CheckListsQuestion"  value="@viewModel.CheckListsQuestion" />
```

I end up with  a null (when I hit submit button). If I bind to ID then I get all fields of CheckListsQuestion empty - only the ID is filled.
Is there a way to load values of all fields from database into an entity based on Id, or is there any better way to deal with bindings?

Answer (score 0):

For now I ended up with `.Attach(); .Reload();` combination like this:

```
var question = questionViewModel.CheckListsQuestion;
_db.CheckListsQuestions.Attach(question);
_db.Entry(question).Reload();
```